# Is it possible to export code and plot (from said code) into a pdf in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, export

I think the question speaks for itself. But I would like to be able to save the code for a ggplot and the ggplot itself in the same pdf document for easy reference.

All the resources I have seen only export the graph by itself.

For example;

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()
```

`ggsave("mtcars.pdf")`

Export both the code and plot...

Comment: Yes, with RMarkdown. http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/

Comment: Or with LaTeX through knitr package

Comment: Easier way ended up just coping code and graph into word.